# Script that automatically closes one program after I manually close another program in Windows

Tags: windows

I need help making a simple script that automatically closes one program after I manually close another program in Windows. For example if I close Battlefield V I want Origin to automatically close after I manually close Battlefield V from inside the game. I want to make a simple batch or power shell script. Would I need to use Task Schedule to do this? Thank you, Jack.

Comment: Can you create a batch file with 2 lines: Line 1: `start /wait battlefieldpathexe` Line 2 `taskkill /F /IM Originprocessname`

Comment: @Jack Does this work for you? If it does, please consider posting it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: This is the batch file I made:
 @echo
start /wait "X:\Orgin Games\Battlefield V\bfv.exe"
taskkill /F /IM Orgin.exe

When I launch battlefield V and then I click the quit button in the game with batch file running Origin stays open. I also noticed that the batch file open two command prompt windows instead of one. It also asks me "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?". Should I launch battlefield and then execute the batch script or should I execute the batch script and then launch battlefield? What should I do now? How can I fix this?